# Error installing ruby-debug/ruby-debug-base with Ruby Enterprise v1.8.7

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, ruby-debug

I got problems when trying to install gem ruby-debug-ide. Then, I try to install gem ruby-debug-base first. However, I got an error:

```
Error installing ruby-debug-base:
rb-threadframe requires Ruby version ~> 1.9.2frame.
```

The same error occured when installing ruby-debug.

I'm using Ubuntu v10.4, Ruby Enterprise v1.8.7, Rubygems v1.8.15.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in new version (0.0.6) of rbx-require-relative that requires rb-threadframe >= 0
Try this:

```
gem install rbx-require-relative -v 0.0.5
gem install linecache ruby-debug-base --ignore-dependencies
```

Comment: added this version of this gem to my gemfile. #ruby-community-fail

Comment: @Anton Topchii : Thanks very much. Now I can install ruby-debug-base, but I still can't install ruby-debug-ide. The console only show: ruby_dir/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb. I have no idea with it. Hope you could help!

Comment: For me, above last command installed `ruby-debug-base` version `0.10.4`. So I installed 'ruby-debugger' by specifying the version `gem install ruby-debug -v=0.10.4`. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty self explanatory.

You need a Ruby version greater than 1.9.2 and you have v1.8.7, will need to get a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this version is required for my work, so I can't update to 1.9.x. Is there any other solution?